# Review my code Funcational Programing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, functional-testing

I try to learn to write functional programming code in react.
could you check and review my code and say to me is it functional or not? or how can I write it better!

Thank you very much

```
    oprationButton(val , oprator){ 

        if(oprator === 'min')
            return this.setState({currentVal: min(val)})
        else if(oprator === 'plus')
            return this.setState({currentVal: plus(val)})

        function min(val){ 
           if (val > 0)
            return val
            else return 0
        }

        function plus(val){
            return val + 1
        }      

}



    <button type="button" 
onClick={() => this.oprationButton(this.state.currentVal,'min')}>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. I recommend improving the title as well.

Comment: Its not that functional, rather imperative. However its functioning and thats what matters.

Comment: ohm, could you review my code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your code like this

```
pluseButton(val, oprator) {
    if (oprator === 'min') {
        let min = this.mines(val)
        return this.setState({currentVal: min})
    } else if (oprator === 'plus')
        return this.setState({currentVal: ++val})
}

mines(val) {
    let sum = val - 1;
    if (sum > 0) return sum
    else return 0
}




 <button type="button" 
onClick={() => this.oprationButton(this.state.currentVal,'min')}>Click Me!</button>
```

I hope this code help u

Answer (score 0):

Since `oprationButton` is mutating the state, which is not an internal variable, and is not returning anything, therefore it is not a `pure` function and it's not `functional programming`. 
On the other hand, your internal functions `plus` and `min` are pure and could be said to be in a functional programming approach.

Comment: it's for onclick like this : onClick={() => this.oprationButton(this.state.currentVal,'min') } ,   how can i change it to be functional!